# Debugging bad_alloc exception from .NET web application

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2008, unmanaged, bad-alloc

I am converting a Visual C++ desktop application to a .NET web application. In doing so, I have tried to retain the backend Visual C++ dlls that were originally used in the desktop application. In an effort to remove global variables from these dll's, I have come across an issue with a bad_alloc exception. This exception seems to come up randomly and I am trying to pinpoint it in the lower level code using many try/catches. I've tried the following, but haven't had much luck:

1) Enabled C++ Exceptions from Debug->Exceptions. (The exception is caught, however the call stack is unhelpful in locating the variable that caused the issue, or even the function).
2) Tried creating a memory leak rule for the VS debugger web server process in DebugDiag. (no leaks were caught).

Any other strategies for tracking this down would be extremely helpful!

Comment: Did you enable Win32 exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Usually C++ operator new() calls the C malloc() function. Operator new throws bad_alloc when malloc() returns 0.  malloc() can return 0 because you are out of memory or because of heap corruption.

Comment: Yes, I understand that would be the cause, however it doesn't help me in pinpointing the issue!

Comment: Finding heap corruption issues is hard because the problem can be in one place but show up in some unrelated place.